# Changing JAX-WS RI of Jboss server to use JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, jax-ws

I am using Jboss-eap-5.1.2 where my web services(SOAP) services are deployed. When I try access them immediately after the server started, I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/xml/bind/JAXBElement;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/UnmarshallerImpl, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader used in the signature
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.createUnmarshaller(JAXBContextImpl.java:738)
```

When I try to access the web services after that, I am getting the following exception:

```
The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:110)
```

I have added a Junit test case to find the root cause. Only one difference I could identify.

`JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01-` is used by the client to generate the stub when I try to access the web services deployed in Jboss from another application.

```
JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01-: Stub for http://10.XX.XXX.16/awdServer/WorkFlowService
```

`JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6` is been used by the client when I try to access the same web services from JUNIT test case.

```
JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6: Stub for http://10.XX.XXX.16/awdServer/WorkFlowService
```

Anybody has any idea on why it is happening like that?

Comment: Looks like you have two separate problems. To sort out the discrepancy in JAX-WS implementations, use the [endorsed directory override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) to direct that your container use a specific version - copy jaxws-api.jar and jaxb-api.jar into your $JDK_HOME/jre/lib/endorsed. The NoClassDefFound indicates that you have duplicate versions of the same class available on your classpath. Use JBoss' tattletale to sniff that out

Comment: @kolossus Thanks for the response. $JDK_HOME/jre/lib doesn't contain any folder named 'endorsed'. If it is the duplicate jar version issue, why the service is called without any issue using JUNIT test case?

Comment: Could you please let me know why and how two versions `JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01- ` and J`AX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6` are chosen?

Comment: You should create it, if it doesn't exist. Classloading in a JavaEE environment is a knotty issue, not something that I can explain in a comment. Suffice it to say, there are two versions, one shipped by the container, another available with the JDK - both are getting crossed at runtime